# How to sort 3 strings variables in alphabetical order with c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have 3 strings variables that user enter three words

and must the program sort them alphabetically what I tried to make it with if statement but the problem is if the user insert the first 5 chars are the same I am tired of repeating the code for every time .

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    string w1,w2,w3;
    cout<<"please enter three words"<<endl;
    cin >> w1 >> w2 >> w3;

    if(w1[0] == w2[0])
    {
        if(w1[1] < w2[1] && w1[0] < w3[0]){
            cout << w1;
            if(w2[0] < w3[0])
            {
                cout << "\t" << w2 <<"\t" << w3;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\t" << w3<<"\t" << w2;
            }
        }else if(w2[1] < w1[1] && w2[0] < w3[0]){
            cout << w2;
            if(w1[0] < w3[0])
            {
                cout << "\t" << w1 <<"\t" << w3;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\t" << w3<<"\t" << w1;
            }

        }else if(w3[0] < w1[0] && w3[0] < w2[0]){
            cout << w3;
            if(w1[1] < w2[1])
            {
                cout << "\t" << w1 <<"\t" << w2;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\t" << w2<<"\t" << w1;
            }

        }
    }
    else if(w2[0] == w3[0])
    {
        if(w1[0] < w2[0] && w1[0] < w3[0]){
            cout << w1;
            if(w2[1] < w3[1])
            {
                cout << "\t" << w2 <<"\t" << w3;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\t" << w3<<"\t" << w2;
            }
        }else if(w2[0] < w1[0] && w2[1] < w3[1]){
            cout << w2;
            if(w1[0] < w3[0])
            {
                cout << "\t" << w1 <<"\t" << w3;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\t" << w3<<"\t" << w1;
            }

        }else if(w3[0] < w1[0] && w3[1] < w2[1]){
            cout << w3;
            if(w1[0] < w2[0])
            {
                cout << "\t" << w1 <<"\t" << w2;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\t" << w2<<"\t" << w1;
            }

        }

    }
    else if(w3[0] == w1[0])
    {
        if(w1[0] < w2[0] && w1[1] < w3[1]){
            cout << w1;
            if(w2[0] < w3[0])
            {
                cout << "\t" << w2 <<"\t" << w3;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\t" << w3<<"\t" << w2;
            }
        }else if(w2[0] < w1[0] && w2[0] < w3[0]){
            cout << w2;
            if(w1[1] < w3[1])
            {
                cout << "\t" << w1 <<"\t" << w3;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\t" << w3<<"\t" << w1;
            }

        }else if(w3[1] < w1[1] && w3[0] < w2[0]){
            cout << w3;
            if(w1[0] < w2[0])
            {
                cout << "\t" << w1 <<"\t" << w2;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\t" << w2<<"\t" << w1;
            }

        }

    }
    else if(w1[0] == w2[0] && w2[0] == w3[0])
    {
        if(w1[1] < w2[1] && w1[1] < w3[1]){
            cout << w1;
            if(w2[1] < w3[1])
            {
                cout << "\t" << w2 <<"\t" << w3;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\t" << w3<<"\t" << w2;
            }
        }else if(w2[1] < w1[1] && w2[1] < w3[1]){
            cout << w2;
            if(w1[1] < w3[1])
            {
                cout << "\t" << w1 <<"\t" << w3;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\t" << w3<<"\t" << w1;
            }

        }else if(w3[1] < w1[1] && w3[1] < w2[1]){
            cout << w3;
            if(w1[1] < w2[1])
            {
                cout << "\t" << w1 <<"\t" << w2;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\t" << w2<<"\t" << w1;
            }

        }
    }
    else if(w1[0] == w2[0] && w2[0] == w3[0] && w1[1] == w2[1] && w2[1] == w3[1])
    {
        if(w1[2] < w2[2] && w1[2] < w3[2]){
            cout << w1;
            if(w2[2] < w3[2])
            {
                cout << "\t" << w2 <<"\t" << w3;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\t" << w3<<"\t" << w2;
            }
        }else if(w2[2] < w1[2] && w2[2] < w3[2]){
            cout << w2;
            if(w1[2] < w3[2])
            {
                cout << "\t" << w1 <<"\t" << w3;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\t" << w3<<"\t" << w1;
            }

        }else if(w3[2] < w1[2] && w3[2] < w2[2]){
            cout << w3;
            if(w1[2] < w2[2])
            {
                cout << "\t" << w1 <<"\t" << w2;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\t" << w2<<"\t" << w1;
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(w1[0] < w2[0] && w1[0] < w3[0]){
            cout << w1;
            if(w2[0] < w3[0])
            {
                cout << "\t" << w2 <<"\t" << w3;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\t" << w3<<"\t" << w2;
            }
        }else if(w2[0] < w1[0] && w2[0] < w3[0]){
            cout << w2;
            if(w1[0] < w3[0])
            {
                cout << "\t" << w1 <<"\t" << w3;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\t" << w3<<"\t" << w1;
            }

        }else if(w3[0] < w1[0] && w3[0] < w2[0]){
            cout << w3;
            if(w1[0] < w2[0])
            {
                cout << "\t" << w1 <<"\t" << w2;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\t" << w2<<"\t" << w1;
            }

        }
    }
    //cout << w1[0] << "\t" << "\t" <<w2[0] << "\t" << w3[0];
    return 0;
}
```

If there a way to make this with for loop but with these libraries only

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
```

Comment: What about putting them into a `std::vector<std::string>` and apply `std::sort()` on it?

Comment: That seems like an incredible amount of code for what should be three compare-and-swap-if-needed operations.

Comment: Since you can't use `std::vector`, put the strings into an array and use `std::sort`, which is in `<algorithm>`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews how to put these strings in an array and use std:sort on it please submit an answer

Comment: @tomfox:  See my answer below.  I have two versions, with and without `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand what your program tries to do. But take into account that class `std::string` has relational operators. So there is no need to compare each character individually.

I would write the program the following way:) You may change the program such a way that it would ask the user to enter three strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    std::string s1 = "tom", s2 = "fox", s3 = "hello";
    auto r1 = std::ref( s1 ), r2 = std::ref( s2 ), r3 = std::ref( s3 );

    if ( r2.get() < r1.get() ) std::swap( r1, r2 );
    if ( r3.get() < r2.get() ) std::swap( r2, r3 );
    if ( r2.get() < r1.get() ) std::swap( r1, r2 );

    std::cout << s1<< '\t' << s2 << '\t' << s3 << std::endl;
    std::cout << r1.get() << '\t' << r2.get() << '\t' << r3.get() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
tom fox hello
fox hello   tom
```

Or you can use a straightforward approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s1 = "tom", s2 = "fox", s3 = "hello";

    if ( s1 <= s2 && s2 <= s3 )
    {
        std::cout << s1<< '\t' << s2 << '\t' << s3 << std::endl;
    }
    else if ( s1 <= s3 && s3 <= s2 )
    {
        std::cout << s1<< '\t' << s3 << '\t' << s2 << std::endl;
    }
    else if ( s2 <= s1 && s1 <= s3 )
    {
        std::cout << s2<< '\t' << s1 << '\t' << s3 << std::endl;
    }
    else if ( s2 <= s3 && s3 <= s1 )
    {
        std::cout << s2<< '\t' << s3 << '\t' << s1 << std::endl;
    }
    else if ( s3 <= s1 && s1 <= s2 )
    {
        std::cout << s3<< '\t' << s1 << '\t' << s2 << std::endl;
    }
    if ( s3 <= s2 && s2 <= s1 )
    {
        std::cout << s3<< '\t' << s2 << '\t' << s1 << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm in the same boat, and was about to link [this sample](http://ideone.com/ITTPU8) as well. Maybe we're both missing something not-so-obvious.

Comment: Where's your `for` loop?  According to the text at the end of the post, "...make this with for loop", there needs to be a `for` loop.

Comment: as maintained above that i can't use any anther libraries expect that in the question

Comment: @ThomasMatthews how I read the text at the end of the question, the OP is asking if there is a way to do this with a loop because he is spewing mountains of code by approaching the problem in an arguably incorrect fashion in the first place. i see no mandate from the unmentioned assignment this **has** to be done with loops.

Comment: @tomfox then just [**do this**](http://ideone.com/ITTPU8). Or perhaps there is something about this problem we don't know ?

Comment: The last "suggestion" is horrible

Comment: @Matt McNabb I showed solutions without swapping the original strings. All other solurions presented here in other posts are wrong from this point of view.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
const unsigned int MAX_STRINGS = 3;
string string_container[MAX_STRINGS];
cout<<"please enter three words"<<endl;
cin >> string_container[0]
    >> string_container[1]
    >> string_container[2];
for (unsigned int i = 1; i < MAX_STRINGS; ++i)
{
     if (string_container[i] <= string_container[i - 1])
     {
       std::swap(string_container[i - 1], string_container[i]);
       i = 0;
     }
}
```

It meets the requirement of having a `for` loop.

**Edit 1:  Using std::sort**
If you don't need a `for` loop:

```
const unsigned int MAX_STRINGS = 3;
string string_container[MAX_STRINGS];
cout<<"please enter three words"<<endl;
cin >> string_container[0]
    >> string_container[1]
    >> string_container[2];
std::sort(&string_container[0], &string_container[MAX_STRINGS];
```

Comment: it doesn't worked if enter aaaaaaaao aaaaaaaaz aaaaaaaaa it gives aaaaaaaao aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaz

Comment: Where does it fail?  Did you use a debugger?

Comment: it doesn't fail but it output a wrong output  if enter aaaaaaaao aaaaaaaaz aaaaaaaaa it outputs aaaaaaaao aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaz

Answer (score 0):

```
int main () {

string list[3];//Array of strings. Makes things easier.
cout<<"please enter three words"<<endl;
cin >> list[0] >> list[1] >> list[2];

//I might be using swap or compare wrong here
//but i guess it it more important that you know these functions exist.
if (list[0].compare(list[1]) < 0) swap(list[0], list[1]);
if (list[0].compare(list[2]) < 0) swap(list[0], list[2]);
if (list[1].compare(list[2]) < 0) swap(list[1], list[2]);

return  0;
}
```

you can also (and more preferably) use a for loop nested within a for loop as such:

```
int arraysize = 3;
for (int i = 0 ; i < arraysize ; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1  ; j < arraysize) ; j++) {
        if (list[i].compare(list[j]) < 0) swap(list[i], list[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it's the code from Thomas Matthews, with a simple [Bubble Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort))

```
const unsigned int MAX_STRINGS = 3;
string string_container[MAX_STRINGS];
cout<<"please enter three words"<<endl;
cin >> string_container[0]
    >> string_container[1]
    >> string_container[2];
bool swaped;

do{
   swaped = false;
   for (unsigned int i = 1; i < MAX_STRINGS; ++i)
   {
        if (string_container[i] <= string_container[i - 1])
        {
          std::swap(string_container[i - 1], string_container[i]);
          swaped = true;
        }
   }
}while(swaped);
```